# Plotting line graph with custom X values

Tags: octave

I'm trying to plot the graph below

[image]

I'm new to GNU Octave and its syntax, I'm not able to correctly write out data points at predetermined X values. I thought writing Y as a 2-dimensional matrix would work (as long as it had the same number of columns as X) but it just made two lines instead of one, like

```
y = [ 0.1, 0.15, 0.2 , 0.3, ... ; 180, 40, -20, -60, ... ]
```

Should I write it as a set of pairs of numbers?

The only thing I got right is the X axis.

```
x = 0;0.5;5;
```

Comment: Typing `help plot` would have solved your problem too. Faster and easier than asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `plot(x,y)` function, it will draw y-values on given x-values.

```
x = [1,2,3,4];
y = [5,8,3,5];
plot(x,y);
```

Comment: What if `x` has to start or end at different values?